# My Listview with a Dynamic Array doesnt change of activity

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, android-listview

Well, I have this problem, i'd like to change from an activity(MenuMeals) to another(EditarPersona), the special thing with my problem is that i use a dynamic array that the class MenuMeal obtains from another activity. Until this point there's no problem.
The problem comes when I'm trying to select an item in the Listview. My idea is that all the items on the listview, when clicked go to EditarPersona no matter what, the thing that changes is a putExtra I added that gives the position of the one i touched which is the one with "PosicionPlatillo".
When I run it, it appears an error saying(The Error from LogCat)
Any ideas what's happening? Or any idea on how to do this correctly?

http://postimg.org/image/hmhm8mb1v/

Code of MenuMeals:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intentobtenido = getIntent();
    Bundle _uso = intentobtenido.getExtras();
    String[] valor = _uso.getStringArray("Comida");
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MenuMeals.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, valor));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    try{    
    Intent editar = new Intent(MenuMeals.this, EditarPersona.class);
    editar.putExtra("PosicionPlatillo", position);
    editar.putExtra("Type", 4);
    startActivity(editar);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    Log.e("Diet Helper", "Exception", e);
    }
}
```

}

Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.albertoha94.apps.diethelper.MenuMeals"
        android:label="@string/editarcomida"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: is your `EditarPersona` activity defined at manifest?

Comment: Instead of posting picture you should copy you log and past it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `EditaPersona` you are trying to set as text your field `Type` in a `TextView`. If you set an int as text for a `TextView` android will look up in the R class for a String with the int you provide as parameter and if it can not found it throws an `ResourceNotFoundException`

Comment: Thanks! With a Simple String.valueOf() everything was resolved. :D

Answer (score 0):

typecast the int position to string and try-- ""+position